# SQL Show Dates Per Status

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a table that looks like so:

```
id    animal_id     transfer_date     status_from       status_to
-----------------------------------------------------------------
100   5265          01-Jul-2016       NULL              P
101   5265          22-Jul-2016       P                 A
102   5265          26-Jul-2016       A                 B
103   5265          06-Aug-2016       B                 A
```

I want to create a view to show me the movement of the animal with start and end dates like the following:

```
animal_id      status      start_date        end_date
---------------------------------------------------------
5265           NULL        NULL              30-Jun-2016
5265           P           01-Jul-2016       21-Jul-2016
5265           A           22-Jul-2016       25-Jul-2016
5265           B           26-Jul-2016       05-Aug-2016
5265           A           06-Aug-2016       SYSDATE OR NULL (current status)
```

As much as I want to provide a query that I've tried, I have none. I don't even know what to search for.

Comment: Assuming you have a table with small number of rows, join the table to itself and see the result. Try working it out from there.

Comment: @NoChance Would around 10k-20k be small enough? This table grows fast though.

Comment: It is common to experiment with how to build queries with small data. I am not suggesting that the OP make the run in production.

Comment: Consider LEAD/LAG analytic functions, it exists in SQL Server, maybe the same is true for ORACLE. For SQL Server: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be more efficient than a join. Alas, I didn't see a way to avoid scanning the table twice.

NOTE: I didn't use an ORDER BY clause (and indeed, if I had the ordering would be weird, since I used to_char on the dates to format them). If you need this in further processing, it is best to NOT wrap the dates within to_char.

```
with
   input_data ( id, animal_id, transfer_date, status_from, status_to) as (
     select 100, 5265, to_date('01-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), null, 'P' from dual union all
     select 101, 5265, to_date('22-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'P' , 'A' from dual union all
     select 102, 5265, to_date('26-Jul-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'A' , 'B' from dual union all
     select 103, 5265, to_date('06-Aug-2016', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'B' , 'A' from dual
   )
select animal_id,
       lag (status_to) over (partition by animal_id order by transfer_date) as status,
       to_char(lag (transfer_date) over (partition by animal_id order by transfer_date),
                                                             'dd-Mon-yyyy') as start_date,
       to_char(transfer_date - 1, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') as  end_date
  from input_data
union all
select     animal_id, 
           max(status_to) keep (dense_rank last order by transfer_date), 
           to_char(max(transfer_date), 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 
           null
  from     input_data
  group by animal_id
;

 ANIMAL_ID STATUS START_DATE           END_DATE           
---------- ------ -------------------- --------------------
      5265                             30-Jun-2016         
      5265 P      01-Jul-2016          21-Jul-2016         
      5265 A      22-Jul-2016          25-Jul-2016         
      5265 B      26-Jul-2016          05-Aug-2016         
      5265 A      06-Aug-2016
```

**Added**: Explanation of how this works. First, there is a "WITH clause" to create the input data from the OP's message; this is a standard technique, anyone who is not familiar with factored subqueries (CTE, WITH clause) - introduced in Oracle 11.1 - will do themselves (and the rest of us!) a lot of good by reading about it/them.

The query joins together rows from two sources. In one branch, I use the `lag()` analytic function; it orders rows, within each group by the columns in the "partition by" clause, according to the ordering by the column in the "order by" clause. So for example, the `lag(status_to)` will look at all the rows within the same `animal_id`, it will order them by `transfer_date`, and for each row, it will pick the status_to from the PREVIOUS row (hence "`lag`"). The rest of that part of the union works similarly.

I have a second part to the union... as you can see in the original post, there are four rows, but the output must have five. In general that suggests a union of some sort will be needed somewhere in the solution (either directly and obviously as in my solution, or via a self-join or in any other way). Here I just another row for the last status (which is still "current"). I use `dense_rank last` which, within each group (how shown in a GROUP BY), selects just the last row by `transfer_date`.

To understand how the query works, it may help to, first, comment out the lines `union all` and `select...  group by animal_id` and run what's left. That will show what the first part of the query does. Then un-comment those lines, and instead comment the first part, from the first `select animal_id` to `union all` (comment these two lines and everything in between). Run the query again, this will show just the last row for each animal_id.

Of course, in the sample the OP provided there is only one `animal_id`; if you like, you can add a few more rows (for example in the WITH clause) with different `animal_id`. Only now the `partition by animal_id` and the `group by animal_id` become important; with only one `animal_id` they wouldn't be needed (for example, if all the rows are already filtered by `WHERE animal_id = 5265` somewhere else in a subquery).

**ADDED #2** - the OP has requested one more version of this - what if the first row is not needed? Then the query is much easier to write and to read. Below I won't copy the CTE (`WITH` clause), and I don't wrap the dates within `to_date()` anymore. No `GROUP BY` is needed, and I didn't order the rows (but the OP can do so if needed).

```
select animal_id,
       status_to as status,
       transfer_date as start_date,
       lead(transfer_date) over (partition by animal_id order by transfer_date) - 1
                                                                             as end_date
  from input_data
;
```

Comment: I tried your query but I didn't include the `with` clause and I got this error: `ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function` and it highlights `lag`. Honestly I have no idea what your query does or what the problem is.

Comment: I also tried your query with the `with` clause included and it seems to work but now I want to have the source data to be my actual data.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio -  Hi Patrick, - then you will want to read about and familiarize yourself with "factored subqueries" (CTE's, "WITH clause"). To use your actual data, remove everything above `select animal_id` - that is where the query actually starts. In two places I wrote `input_data`, that is the alias I have for my factored subquery in the WITH clause; replace both instances with your actual table name. Make sure your column names are EXACTLY as you wrote in your post, as I used them exactly. Not sure about the error you got; there is a "default" window for `lag()`

Comment: I will add an explanation of what the query does in the Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I created a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/at6SQ6gN) for you to look at what I'm using. Could you check what I did wrong there?

Comment: Oh, hey - I found my mistake, I had a `,` after the first `LAG(status_to)`. It's working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: So what if I need to remove the very first row for each animal (ones with no status)? I tried to add `WHERE status_to IS NOT NULL` on the first `SELECT` clause but I'm still getting them.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio - then the query becomes MUCH simpler (and easier to understand!) - I will add to my Answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Virtual hugs!!

Comment: Hey I was browsing some of the returned rows and there were a couple that had an end date earlier than the start date. This happens for both approaches you mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the solution correctly? What you say doesn't sound right, since - for example - the second query has `transfer_date` and `lead(transfer_date)` on the same row (`lead` is ordered by `transfer_date`, ascending and with nulls last by default)- so it is really not possible that the second date is before the first. Please check to make sure you used the solution correctly. Or, if you can just isolate the few rows that cause the wrong output, please post them so I can check for myself.

Comment: Here's a copy and paste of what I ended up using: [Pastbin](http://pastebin.com/htwqUhFi) - please take a look.

Comment: What happened was that the transfer date happened all on the same day. So if the next row happened on the same day then you subtract 1 you get an earlier date.

Comment: Oh, you mean you had a status change at 9 am and then another status change at 3 pm on the same day? Then the requirement (to show just dates, and to show the end of a status as the day BEFORE the change) is inconsistent with what may happen in real life. Not much you or I can do about that!

Comment: I looked at what you posted and I have a few questions... you use TRUNC() as if you have dates with a time-of-day component; you didn't mention that until now. Also, if all you want to show is the date, you don't need to truncate; when you use TO_CHAR() with the dd/mm/yyyy mask or similar, the result will be the same with or without TRUNC.

Comment: Yes that's what happened sorry I failed to mention this on the question, I just saw it today too so I didn't know. You mean I can't have it display the same day instead though instead of subtracting 1?

Comment: Oh ok, I'll take out the `TRUNC` function there. Yes it's a timestamp field but we're really only after the date. I'm using time of the day here only to sort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121367/discussion-between-mathguy-and-patrick-gregorio).